# Android: Saving data to server avoiding activity destroy

Tags: android, android-activity, service, save

Is there a way to prevent activity get destroy when saving in progress to the server? I have a profile activity which allow user to save the profile to server. I show a progress dialog but there is a chance the activity get destroy when it go  to the background. When it go back to front, the progress dialog will disappear but the background saving still executing.

Comment: need more information, what is your *progress dialog*?

Comment: It was just a dialogFragment and was set not allow to cancel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe starting a service to do the upload job would suit you better and you won't have to worry about the activity getting destroyed. You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html) about creating/sending info to a service.

Comment: I am using the Volley library to do the communication part and normal thread to do imaging operation. I think the volley library should have done the background stuff for me. My problem is the progress dialog. If activity got destroy, the progress dialog itself also got destroy. So if activity get re-create, the progress dialog will no longer there even though saving still in progress.

Comment: Hmm, should be a simple task, but I don't think there's a straight forward way with volley - when the activity gets destroyed, the request listener is the destroyed activity and the response/error won't get called on the new one (so it's hard to keep track of the request status - using shared preferences for example). One way would be to cancel the request and start it again in the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AsyncTask to do the job, you should not have any problem since Asynctask is not destroyed when the activity dies.

Otherwise creating a service maybe the best way to handle it.

Hope this helps.